# Qu'est-ce qu'une « cellule numérique » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, terminologie, ellipse

On peut [lire](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/201901/15/01-5211033-campagne-sur-twitter-contre-un-dissident-saoudien-au-quebec.php) que le *New York Times* [rapportait](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/20/us/politics/saudi-image-campaign-twitter.html) que l'Arabie Saoudite, gouvernée par une famille dont la tête dirigeante a fort probablement [commandité](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/moyen-orient/201901/03/01-5209814-meurtre-de-khashoggi-ouverture-du-proces-cinq-peines-de-mort-requises.php) l'assassinat d'un journaliste pour ensuite faire découper son corps à la scie par un « médecin » chantant, avait fondé en 2010 une « [...] ***cellule numérique*** destinée à harceler les dissidents du Royaume, notamment par l'entremise de trolls qui s'évertuent à discréditer les personnes visées, ternir leur image et retourner l'opinion publique contre eux » (La Presse)<sup>1</sup>.

---

- Quelle est la définition de *cellule numérique* ; sur quelle
  acception de [*cellule*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cellule) se base-t-on ; y a-t-il ellipse d'un
  terme et si oui, duquel ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On en a déjà eu des exemples quand ces derniers ont tenté de [faire croire](https://www.lapresse.ca/techno/reseaux-sociaux/201808/06/01-5192087-des-trolls-saoudiens-appuient-lindependance-du-quebec-sur-twitter.php) qu'ils s'intéressaient au sort des membres des Premières nations du Canada ou à l'indépendance du Québec (en confondant le drapeau de la province avec celui de la ville de Québec, démontrant un niveau d'ignorance crasse qu'ils auraient dû corriger en laissant leurs citoyens [étudier](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/201808/06/01-5192133-les-etudiants-saoudiens-font-les-frais-de-la-querelle-ottawa-riyad.php) davantage au Canada, à l'évidence), et maintenant aux droits des animaux et à la nudité d'une de leur ressortissante alors que leur pays traite les femmes comme des [esclaves](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/201901/14/01-5211028-la-saoudienne-refugiee-au-canada-raconte-son-ancienne-vie-desclave.php) et soumet des personnes à des [châtiments cruels](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/national/201901/13/01-5210875-laccueil-de-la-jeune-saoudienne-ne-nuira-pas-a-raif-badawi.php) et indignes d'un être humain. Comme l'état [Russe](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/201811/14/01-5204255-des-trolls-russes-ont-attaque-le-canada.php), peu satisfait de ses [positions](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/201811/30/01-5206266-front-uni-du-g7-contre-lagression-russe-en-ukraine.php), et [maintenant](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-canadienne/201901/14/01-5210912-trudeau-denonce-la-condamnation-a-mort-dun-canadien-en-chine.php) l'État communiste chinois qui s'immisce encore davantage dans son système de justice qui n'est même pas digne d'un tel nom (*mascarade* conviendrait davantage), on cible le Canada parce que, comme le [dit](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/national/201901/14/01-5210908-rahaf-mohammed-al-qunun-lhistoire-dune-fuite-planifiee.php) Mme Rahaf Mohammed al-Qunun en ce qui a trait à sa situation, « [l]e seul pays qui m'ait vraiment aidée finalement est le Canada. Les autres ont eu peur et sont des lâches ». On se demande si on va arrêter de [tergiverser](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/moyen-orient/201810/20/01-5201042-affaire-khashoggi-berlin-pret-a-geler-ses-ventes-darmes-vers-riyad.php) avec les droits de l'homme par intérêt pour la vente d'armes et si on va enfin comprendre que l'Arabie Saoudite n'est digne d'[aucun mandat](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/moyen-orient/201812/16/01-5208244-larabie-saoudite-condamne-lingerence-du-senat-americain.php) de l'Occident ni la condition préalable d'une quelconque [normalisation](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/moyen-orient/201808/27/01-5194409-la-paix-avec-les-palestiniens-passe-par-la-normalisation-avec-les-pays-arabes.php) régionale au Moyen-Orient. Quand va-t-on enfin avoir le courage de se battre comme nos grands-parents l'ont fait lors de la 2e pour défendre la dignité humaine contre le fascisme ?</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ici, cellule se rapporte à la définition suivante :

> **B.−** *P. anal. et au fig.*
>   **1.** Élément d'un groupe social organisé. *La famille (...) cellule première du tissu social* (R. Martin du Gard, *Les Thibault*,La Sorellina, 1928, p. 1152).*Ma paroisse (...) cellule vivante de l'église impérissable* (Bernanos, *Journal d'un curé de campagne*,1936, p. 1052):
>
> - 7. ... c'était charmant de voir cette grand'mère et cette fille (...)    mûrir ce modeste bonheur et s'orienter, sans le savoir, à 
>        reconstruire dans Metz une **cellule** *française*. Barrès, *Colette
>
>        Baudoche*,1909, p. 28.
>
> **2.** *Emplois spéc.*   − *SOCIOL.* *Un petit nombre de combattants groupés dans les corps francs et les cellules professionnelles* (De
>   Gaulle, *Mémoires de guerre*,1956, p. 477).*Une cellule de
>   consommation* (Perroux, *L'Écon. du XXes.*,1964, p. 439).

(http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cellule)

Il s'agit dans ce cas particulier d'un groupe de quelques individus unis ou susceptible de s'unir pour effectuer des actions "*destinée*s *à harceler les dissidents du Royaume*" via des moyens numériques (réseaux sociaux, forums, etc).

Ce terme est régulièrement employé pour désigner un groupe de personnes réunies autour d'un objectif particulier : [cellule terroriste](https://www.ouest-france.fr/terrorisme/maroc-une-cellule-terroriste-affiliee-l-etat-islamique-demantelee-5953484), [cellule de crise](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/nouvelle-aquitaine/creuse/gueret/agriculture-eleveurs-creusois-reunis-cellule-crise-cherchent-fourrages-1598969.html), [cellule d'investigation](https://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2018/02/25/2748710-gendarmerie-cellule-investigation-criminelle-pays-lapins-blancs.html), etc